# New fog models missing from gem

Tags: models, openstack, fog

I have been adding some new models and requests to [fog.](https://github.com/fog/fog)

When I build the gem with

```
rake build
```

and install with

```
gem install pkg/fog-1.23.0.gem
```

The gem installs, and existing files that I modified are present, but the new models and requests aren't included.  Is there something else that needs updated to add new models to Fog ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: you'll need to add the `model` and `request` calls to the appropriate `Service` subclass. For example, see [this section](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/openstack/compute.rb#L14-L172) of the `Fog::OpenStack::Compute` service to see how compute models and requests are included.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.
Looking at the gem, I saw that only files under git were included:

```
s.files = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
```

Adding my files to git and rebuilding successfully included the files.